# passing positive results from multiple columns into a single new column in r

Tags: r, for-loop, calculated-columns

I am trying to work out a way to create a single column from multiple columns in R. What I want to do is for R to go through all rows for multiple columns and if it finds a positive result in one of those columns, to pass that result into an 'amalgam' column (sorry I don't know a better word for it).

See the toy dataset below

```
x <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1)
y <- c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA)
z <- c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA)

df <- data.frame(cbind(x, y, z))

df[, "compCol"] <- NA

df

   x  y  z compCol
1 NA NA NA      NA
2 NA NA  1      NA
3 NA  1 NA      NA
4 NA NA NA      NA
5 NA NA NA      NA
6  1 NA NA      NA
```

I need to pass positive results from each of the columns into the compCol column while changing negative results to 0. So that it looks like this.

```
   x  y  z compCol
1 NA NA NA       0
2 NA NA  1       3
3 NA  1 NA       2
4 NA NA NA       0
5 NA NA NA       0
6  1 NA NA       1
```

I know if probably requires an if else statement nested inside a for loop but all the ways I have tried result in errors that I don't understand.

I tried the following just for a single column

```
 for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (df$x[i] == 1) {
    df$compCol[i] <- df$x[i]
    }   
 }
```

But it didn't work at all.

I got the message 'Error in if (df$x[i] == 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'

And that makes sense but I can't see where to put the TRUE/FALSE statement

Comment: Please, don't do `data.frame(cbind(x, y, z))`. Simply `data.frame(x, y, z)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `max.col`.  Create a logical matrix by checking whether the selected columns are greater than 0 and are not NA ('ind').  We use `max.col` to get the column index for each row and multiply with `rowSums` of 'ind' so that if there is 0 TRUE values for a row, it will be 0.

```
 ind <- df > 0 & !is.na(df)
 df$compCol <- max.col(ind) *rowSums(ind)
 df$compCol
 #[1] 0 3 2 0 0 1
```

---

Or another option is `pmax` after multiplying with the `col(df)`

```
do.call(pmax,col(df)*replace(df, is.na(df), 0))
#[1] 0 3 2 0 0 1
```

NOTE: I used the dataset before creating the 'compCol' in the OP's post.

Comment: So elegant! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use reshaping with NA removal

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df.id = df %>% mutate(ID = 1:n() )

df.id %>%
  gather(variable, value, 
         x, y, z, 
         na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(df.id)
```